# Why would a website say it's running on nginx through telnet, but say Apache through directory browsing?

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4

Running "telnet website.com 80 HEAD / HTTP/1.0" claims that the server is nginx/1.14.1, however directory browsing is enabled on the site and visiting it clearly says "Apache Server at website.com Port 80". What could cause this?

Comment: You should ask the person who runs the server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For me there are two possible explanations.

First the owner compile own version of apache and replace the identification string to mislead (attackers, externals...). The good security practice tell this ID banner should be disabled at all.
Second, directory listing you see is from apache, but the frontend server is nginx which proxy requests to apache (for directory)

Answer (score 4):

It's quite common for nginx to be used as a reverse proxy in front of the actual web server; this would explain your results, as the HTTP connection is served by nginx, but the real site contents are provided by Apache.